# Kusto: How Do I Find all Databases which have a Table by its name within a Kusto Server

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Kusto server. The server has multiple Databases.
I have a Table name, let's say Table1. But I don't know which database or databases have that table.
Is there a Kusto query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.show databases schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-schema-database)

```
.show databases schema 
| where isempty(ColumnName)
| where TableName == "Customers"
```

| DatabaseName | TableName | ColumnName | ColumnType | IsDefaultTable | IsDefaultColumn | PrettyName | Version | Folder | DocString |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ContosoSales | Customers |  |  | false | false |  |  |  |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA9MrzsgvV0hJLElMSixOLVYoTs5IzU1U4KpRKM9ILUpVyCxOzS0oqdRwzs8pzc3zS8xN1YTLhSQm5aSChBRsbRWUnEuLS/JzU4uKlQBC1ONYVAAAAA==)

---

Following the OP question:

```
.show databases schema 
| take 5
```

- The 1st row describes the database
- The 2nd row describes the table
- The other rows describe the columns

| DatabaseName | TableName | ColumnName | ColumnType | IsDefaultTable | IsDefaultColumn | PrettyName | Version | Folder | DocString |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Samples |  |  |  | false | false |  | v3333.3 |  |  |
| Samples | StormEvents |  |  | false | false |  |  | Storm_Events | US storm events. Data source: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/stormevents |
| Samples | StormEvents | StartTime | System.DateTime | false | false |  |  |  |  |
| Samples | StormEvents | EndTime | System.DateTime | false | false |  |  |  |  |
| Samples | StormEvents | EpisodeId | System.Int32 | false | false |  |  |  |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA9MrzsgvV0hJLElMSixOLVYoTs5IzU1U4KpRKEnMTlUwBQCham4ZIAAAAA==)

Comment: Thanks David. One query. Why does each table have a Column with no name? isempty(ColumnName)

Comment: This command shows data on database, tables and columns. If the TableName and ColumnName are empty, then it is a database row. If only ColumnName is empty, then it is a table row. If neither is empty, then this a column row.